# How can I generate sql inserts from pipe delimited data?

Tags: elisp

Given a set of delimited data in the following format:

```
1|Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope|1977|Action,Sci-Fi|George Lucas
2|Titanic|1997|Drama,History,Romance|James Cameron
```

In **elisp**, how can I generate sql insert statements in this format?

```
insert into table 
   values(1,"Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope",1977","Action,Sci-Fi","George Lucas",0);
insert into table 
   values(2,"Titanic",1997,"Drama,History,Romance","James Cameron",0);
```

To simplify the problem, let's allow for a parameter to tell which
columns are text or numeric. (e.g. 0,1,0,1,1)

Here's how I would do it in Perl.

```
my @ctypes=qw/0 1 0 1 1/;

while(<>) {
  chop;
  @F=split('\|', $_);
  print "insert into table values(";
  foreach my $col (@F) {
    my $type=shift(@ctypes);
    print ($type == 1 ? '"'.$col.'"' : $col);
    print ",";
  }

  print "0);\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert the data at the end of a buffer:

```
(require 'cl)
(defun* insert-statements (rows ctypes &key (table-name "table") (delimiter "|"))
  (let* ((values-template 
          (mapconcat '(lambda (type) (if (= type 1) "\"%s\"" "%s")) ctypes ","))
         (template (format "insert into %s values(%s);\n" table-name values-template)))
    (mapcar '(lambda (row) (insert (apply 'format (cons template (split-string row delimiter)))))
            rows)))

(let ((data "1|Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope|1977|Action,Sci-Fi|George Lucas
2|Titanic|1997|Drama,History,Romance|James Cameron")
      (ctypes '(0 1 0 1 1)))
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (insert-statements (split-string data "\n") ctypes)))
```

This solution may not scale well compared with the Perl solution.

Alternatively, we could insert the values into a database using SqlMode:

```
(require 'cl)
(defun* insert-statements (rows ctypes &key (table-name "table") (delimiter "|"))
  (let* ((values-template 
            (mapconcat '(lambda (type) (if (= type 1) "\"%s\"" "%s")) ctypes ","))
         (template (format "insert into %s values(%s);" table-name values-template)))
    (mapcar '(lambda (row) (sql-send-string
                            (apply 'format (cons template (split-string row delimiter)))) )
            rows)))
(sql-sqlite)
(sql-send-string "create table test (id, title, yr, genre, director);")
(let ((data "1|Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope|1977|Action,Sci-Fi|George Lucas
2|Titanic|1997|Drama,History,Romance|James Cameron")
      (ctypes '(0 1 0 1 1)))
  (insert-statements (split-string data "\n") ctypes :table-name 'test))
(sql-send-string "select title from test;")
(sql-send-string "drop table test;")
```

Comment: This inserts into the message window, which isn't very accessible.  How can I insert at the end of the buffer?

Comment: I have now revised the solution to insert text at the end of the buffer and included an approach using SqlMode to insert the values into a database.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a simple program to go through each line and look for delimiter | and generate insert statements. if you are familiar with using mysql you can import the data into mysql table using "load data" command. you will have to have the data in file though

Comment: I would like an answer in elisp.